# parse all the servers from sys.servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

Is there a nice way to parse through all the servers from sys.servers (Sql Server) and run the same query in each one? Maybe only the database will be different, but we can do without this detail. Let's suppose the database has the same name on each server. The query will always be the same, only the server name and address will differ, in each case.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use dynamic SQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but as a work around you can register the servers in SSMS within the same group and then execute a SQL statement to the group, this will execute the same code on each server.

[image]

Useful if you need to run the same query on an ad-hoc basis. You can also setup a centralised management server with all the registrations
[Create a Central Management Server and Server Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx)

> This topic describes how to designate an instance of SQL Server as a
>   central management server in SQL Server 2016 by using SQL Server
>   Management Studio. Central management servers store a list of
>   instances of SQL Server that is organized into one or more central
>   management server groups. Actions that are taken by using a central
>   management server group act on all servers in the server group. This
>   includes connecting to servers by using Object Explorer and executing
>   Transact-SQL statements and Policy-Based Management policies on
>   multiple servers at the same time.